# Reading activity InArgument values

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

I am creating a custom native activity using workflow foundation 4.5. I want to set a bookmark for the activity and do some custom handling in the WorkflowApplication's PersistableIdle callback.  Within that callback I want to read the data that was provided into the activity's InArgument<> and/or Properties before the workflow instance is persisted away.  So essentially, I want to read these values from outside the context of the activity that executed and outside the run time as a pre-step before completing the persistence process.

I thought I might be able to do this with the WorkflowInspectionServices helper class but it's unclear if that works given I have to context to read from that activity instance's InArgument<>.

Is there another helper class that can make this happen with wf4.5 that I haven't discovered yet? Thanks.

```
 wfApp.PersistableIdle += args =>
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
            {
                wfApp.Unload();
                args.Bookmarks.ForEach(bookmark =>
                {
                    var activityId = bookmark.BookmarkName;

                    //Doesn't seem this will really work?
                    var activityInfo = WorkflowInspectionServices.Resolve(activity, activityId) as MyCustomActivity;


                    var recipientId = activityInfo.RecipientId.Get(<I have no context>);
                   workflowSuspendedCallback.Invoke(activityId, recipientId));
                });
                scope.Complete();
            }
            return PersistableIdleAction.None;
        };
```

Comment: Simply create your own [workflow extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff460215(v=vs.100).aspx) to get this information from your activity.

Comment: Awesome. Nice hook into the run time.  I was also looking at the Workflow Tracker but that seemed overkill since I only care about certain activities.

Answer (score 0):

The use of [activity extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff460215(v=vs.100).aspx) did the trick.
Thanks Will.